# Android : Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator HAXM installer - "revision: 7.5.6" update failed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, haxm, android-studio-3.6

Recently, I have installed **Android Studio 3.6.1**, I got a recommendation to update SDK and other tools.

I am trying to update **Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.5.6)** but getting problem as below:

```
Packages to install: 
- Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager)
Preparing "Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.5.6)".
Downloading http://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/haxm-windows_v7_5_6.zip
"Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.5.6)" ready.
Installing Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) in E:\Android\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager
"Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.5.6)" complete.
Failed to update status to COMPLETE
"Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.5.6)" failed.
Failed packages:
- Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager)
```

[image]

```
Failed to update Intel HAXM. For details, please check the installation log: "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1\haxm_log.txt"
HAXM installation failed. To install HAXM follow the instructions found at: https://software.intel.com/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows
Installer log is located at C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1\haxm_log.txt
Installer log contents:
=== Logging started: 05/03/2020  16:26:11 ===
Intel HAXM driver instance loaded. Installation could not be continued.
=== Logging stopped: 05/03/2020  16:26:11 ===
Done
```

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: @Pawandeep No its not working, I have open this issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/intel/haxm/issues/273) too

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got an answer on [GitHub](https://github.com/intel/haxm/issues/273#issuecomment-597980324):

I have downloaded manually from https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases/download/v7.5.6/haxm-windows_v7_5_6.zip

Unzipped that downloaded file and Install **intelhaxm-android.exe**

After that I have tried to install HAXM from **Android Studio -> SDK Manager** and Its get worked.

Comment: In my windows system, virtualization is enabled and Hyper-v is disabled. I have installed the HAXM setup from above link though it didn't work. Please provide some help to get over this issue.

Comment: Thanks. This installer told me that Hyper-V was active as Windows Feature. The installation in AndroidStudio did not show that error.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. The problem was the version of Intel Accelerated:

> Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager is already installed.
> The current installation will exit. If you really want to downgrade,
> you can uninstall the newer version from the control panel first and
> then install the older version

So, I uninstalled Intel Accelerated from Control panel and installed it again from Android Studio-> Android SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I had various errors with the Intel HAXM, checked the BIOS and used the check tool, https://github.com/intel/haxm/release:

> checktool.exe --verbose

CPU vendor          *  GenuineIntel
Intel64 supported   *  Yes
VMX supported       *  Yes
VMX enabled         *  Yes
EPT supported       *  Yes
NX supported        *  Yes
NX enabled          *  Yes
Hyper-V disabled    *  Yes
OS version          *  Windows 6.1.7601
OS architecture     *  x86_64
Guest unoccupied    *  Yes. 0 guest(s)

I downloaded version 7_5_6 using link above and ran the .bat file from the command prompt to install and it worked.

Visual Studio 2019:
The procedure of selecting the HAXM installer in Tools > Android SDK Manager in Visual Studio had problems with process sharing, the stand alone C:\Program Files (x86)\Xamarin\AndroidSDKManager\AndroidSdkManager.exe also gave me errors.

Answer (score 0):

Is more easy, just go in

**Apparence & Behavoir > System Settigns > Android SDK** and just select HAXM for install...

anyway you need enabled virtualization on your bios.

Answer (score 0):

if you have an intel processor just enable intel virtual technology on bios and it will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on virtualization technology  (VT -x) from bios.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).